# 3 tables ... one datagrid? C# with SQL Server and IIS ...?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm kinda stuck ... I have three tables... I'll simplify ...

- `tbl_MyTopics`: ID int, DateEntered datetime, Topic varchar(50), Note varchar(1000)
- `tbl_MyComments`: ID int, DateEntered datetime, ID_MyTopics int, Comment varchar(1000)
- `tbl_MyAttachments`: ID int, DateEntered datetime, ID_MyTopics int, ID_MyComments int, PathAttachment nvarchar(1000)

Obviously, create a topic, add multiple comments (MyTopics.ID = MyComments.ID_MyTopics)

Also, add multiple attachments for topics or comments (MyTopics.ID = MyAttachments.ID_MyTopics and/or MyComments.ID=MyAttachments.ID_MyComments)

The ABOVE logic (if not clear in my writing above) is working perfectly in the DB and basically if you ever post a COMMENT on a TOPIC ... it connects the comment to the topic by Topic.ID and if you add an attachment via a comment, or directly to the topic, it connects the ATTACHMENT to the TOPIC or the COMMENT ... everything flows back to the TOPIC.

I have built the pages for entry, and have a multiple file drop/drag uploader and it populates the tables properly, builds thumbnails, tracks everything for logging, emails based on other logic and all that good stuff.

NOW ... I'm onto the presentation piece ... and I need a kick in the head ...

I want to present it like the image below ... (I have the SQL query getting me data ... but I'm stuck on where to go with datasets and how to populate tables inside of tables and if I need to iterate multiple times with some kind of cursor on the DB) ...

For example:

1. Say I buy a bike lock... I take a picture of it and the receipt
2. Post it via my existing forms into the DB
3. Bike lock breaks a week later, so I return it ...
4. I show the clerk my receipt from my phone... She processes the return ...
5. I photograph the return receipt and save it as a comment...

I would like to show it like this in a web form ...

[This is what it should look like ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQMwq.png)

Has anyone ever tackled something remotely like this or have any thoughts about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the classes you are populating from DB? I think the more organized way to do that is to create a View class for the Topic that your presentation layer is going to use. It should have a list of comments and attachments. Your comments should also have a list attachments. That way you could iterate it when presenting in the front end. You can also use it to include other properties like the image content and URL (in the case you are not saving it to database). At least that the path I would go...Not sure if I anwsered your question though

Comment: Agreed Kim and yes I'm using a DB and you did give me something to think on, thank you!  I upload the images to the server, then note the unique location of each in the DB and link them to the topic.  I have three small tables: Topics, Comments & Attachments.  A topic could be a single entry with no comments/attachments BUT it could have many comments and/or attachments.  SO ... instead of doing a cursor on every lookup (as I am now) was wondering if there was a less complex TSQL to pull the data more efficiently when joining three tables.